# Does the thermal expansion of a conductor contribute to its change in resistance when it is heated?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

We know that the resistance of a conductor varies with a change in temperature and we are taught that this change occurs due to the change in resistivity of the material but does the thermal expansion of a conductor also affect its resistance?

Comment: Since both effects depend on temperature, it is very difficult to separate them.  I suspect that resistivity is measured without compensating for expansion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For copper the temperature coefficient of resistivity is $3.9\times 10^{-3} \text{K}^{-1} $ and the temperature coefficient of thermal linear expansion is $1.6\times 10^{-4} \text{K}^{-1} $.  They differ by a factor of about 24 so a change in temperature will cause a bigger change in resistance than in the linear dimensions of copper.

Resistance is given by $\frac{\rho L}{A}$ where $\rho$ is the resistivity, $L$ is the length and $A$ is the area of the copper.
Any thermal expansion will cause a bigger fraction change in the area $\propto \text{linear dimension}^2$ than in the length $\propto \text{linear dimension}$.  So as a result of thermal expansion the resistance of the copper will decrease when the temperature.

So the net effect will be an increase in the resistance of a specimen of copper.

I have found that [Kaye and Laby](http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/) are an invaluable source of physical constants.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Farcher! That really helped clear my doubt! I wonder that there may be materials with such low coefficients of temperature of resistance that their resistance would actually drop on heating rather than increase.

Comment: @Aniansh, Semiconductors indeed show a reasonable drop in resistance on heating. Also, there coefficients of thermal expansions are very low. So, maybe linear expansion is the reason of change of resistance.

Comment: @Aniansh, See this table: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/thexp.html

Comment: The thermal expansion coefficient of silicon (a semiconductor) is about 2.6×10^-6 °C^-1. Just compare this value to the other values mentioned in the Celsius part of the table and you will know the difference.